# How can I access a widget from another widget tree using kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make an app using kivy that will pass the text from a textinput widget to a button widget that both have different widget trees, can I do this because I can't seem to find anything in the docs about this.

My python code:

```
class Tes(App):
    pass

class Text(TextInput):
    pass

class Buton(Button):
    def on_push(self, text):
        print 'keep it up' + text


if __name__=='__main__':
    Tes().run()
```

My Kivy code:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0


FloatLayout

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 1, 0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    TextInput:
        text: 'hi'
        id: text
        size_hint: (.5, .5)
        pos_hint: {'top': .4, 'left': .4}

    Text
    Buton



<Text>
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
    size_hint: (.1, .1)
    id: text

<Buton>
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'left': 1}
    size_hint: (.1, .1)
    id: button
    on_press: self.on_push(root.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

An `id` property is limited to the scope of a rule. The `id` here:

```
<Text>
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
    size_hint: (.1, .1)
    id: text
```

Does nothing, because there are no other widgets in the rule, which could potentially access it. So, move the `id` to the upper rule:

```
FloatLayout
    ...
    TextInput:
        id: text
        ...
    Text:
        id: label_text
    Buton:
        id: buton
```